# Change image selected when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, image, input, selected

What is the simplest way to change the image selected (`class=selected`) when a form element is selected?  I've tried several different methods (unsuccessfully) but my Javascript is a bit rusty so I could use some help.

I am displaying an image next to each set of radio buttons which depicts the value when hovered or selected. In addition, I've pre-`selected` a default value to be displayed initially (usually the most popular answer).  The css ensures that the relevant images are displayed in a fixed position, and the `z-index` and `opacity` change in order to display the correct image. The only problem is that when the user clicks on a radio button it on, the value is correctly set to `selected` but the corresponding image is not being selected.

I have included the relevant snippets below and **[posted a fiddle with the full css here](http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/TR3Te/10/).**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .new li img {
            opacity: 0;}
    .new li.selected img {
            z-index: 2;
            opacity: 1;}
    .new:hover li.selected img {
            z-index: 0;}
    .new li:hover img {
            z-index: 2;
            opacity: 1;}
</style>

<div class="new alternate_image">
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="sports.png" />
    <label><input type="radio" name="item1" value="Sports"/>Sports</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="fashion.png" />
    <label><input type="radio" name="item1" value="Fashion"/>Fashion</label>
  </li>
  <li class="selected">
    <img src="city.png" />
    <label><input type="radio" name="item1" value="City"/>City</label>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any code that would cause the selected class to be added to an element or removed from the one it starts with.

Comment: @j08691 - I've actually tried doing that several different ways but couldn't get it to work so I finally decided to ask for help ;-)

Comment: If I got you correctly you want to change the image if we select any radio button? If yes then check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F6zPc/8/

Comment: @SystematixInfotech - It looks like that should do the trick but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into my existing code (so that I don't have to rewrite the code for apx. 50 sets of radio buttons). Could you show me how to get it to work with the sample code in my fiddle, so that it'll work with my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

The following will do the job.  Though since it will affect all radio buttons, you may want to tweak the first selector (e.g. `'.alternate_image input[type=radio]'`).

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    var name = this.name;
    var self = this;
    $('input[name=' + name + ']').each(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('selected', this === self);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nonplus/qF3P9/1/